# Regarding $F_4$ and $G_2$ Lie algebras, do there exist $F_n$ or $G_n$ families of Lie algebras?

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-algebras, root-systems, coxeter-groups

For example, $E_6$ exceptional Lie algebra is part of the $E_n$ series of Lie algebras (Kac-Moody algebras). Are $F_4$ or $G_2$ maybe also parts of some $F_n$ or $G_n$ series of Lie algebras or are they isolated cases?

Comment: I'd guess $F_n$ has two natural extrapolations $o-o\stackrel{4}-o-o-\dots-o$, with the two possible orientations for the 4-arrow (irrelevant for the Coxeter version), and similarly $G_2$ has two natural extrapolations $o\stackrel{6}-o-o-\dots-o$ with either orientations for the 6-arrow.

Comment: The families suggested by @YCor have the nice property that they contain the affine Lie algebras related to finite types $F_4$ and $G_2$.  (In Kac's notation, these are $F_4^{(1)}$, $E_6^{(2)}$, $G_2^{(1)}$, and $D_4^{(3)}$.)  Of course, the $E_n$ series does not contain the affine $E_6^{(1)}$ or $E_7^{(1)}$ Lie algebras, so maybe that's not a necessary feature.

Comment: Another way to look at the extrapolations suggested by @YCor is by means of diagram folding. Namely, $G_2$ is an order 3 folding of $D_4$, while $F_4$ is an order 2 folding of $E_6$. This can be continued to the 2- and 3-foldings of the diagrams of types $Y_{n,n,n}$ and $Y_{n,n,1}$ respectively. Other options include $n$-folding of the diagram with $n$ nodes connected by simple edges to a single vertex (then one gets $C_2$, $G_2$, $A_{2}^{(2)}$, $H(1,5)$, etc.) But since there is no description of a single KM-algebra but by generators and relations, this is all just speculations.